# Oracle service and oracle smart contract

Tags: web3js, contract-development, blockchain, javascript, oracles

I read this article https://medium.com/@robinagist/building-an-ethereum-oracle-with-web3-js-1-0-1272b59cfc31 but there are some things I didn't understand. Does the oracle need a node (like geth or parity) to communicate with the oracle smart contract?
At this link there is the code https://github.com/robinagist/EthereumWeatherOracle in wxoracle.js I did not understand the sleep function what it is for.

Comment: yeah , it needs a node because it needs to send a transaction to feed the data about weather every hour or so to update the temperatures. Or this node can be "borrowed" from Infura.

Comment: the `sleep()` function is probably because every X minutes of time, somebody needs to feed temperatures to the contract

Comment: @Nulik thank you. I noticed that the same sleep function is present in the client. What is it for here?

Comment: @Nulik also in this article there is a wait function which I cannot understand <https://medium.com/decentlabs/building-your-first-ethereum-oracle-1ab4cccf0b31>. Should it have the same purpose?

Comment: I don't know , what is the `resolve()` function doing? thats the answer

Comment: these things are more Javascript specific, promise and setTimeout

Comment: whatever these functions are doing, this is not related to the Oracle, one requirement of the Oracle service is that someone needs to feed the data, wether it is going to be a human, typing on the keyboard, or a javascript script sending a Tx in an automated way